# Decrease disk space requirements for git-annex on Windows

Tags: windows, file-management, git-bash, git-annex

Currently, I am evaluating git-annex to track larger files on disconnected media.
After adding files to annex on Windows, I noticed that the disk space doubles as hashed content resides in the workdir and in `.git/annex/objects`. On NTFS I would have expected that hardlinks or symlinks would have been used so that there is only a single copy of each file.

I've read about `direct` mode but this seems to be outdated. Is there a way on Windows to reduce the disk space requirements? I think the same issue could occur on Linux when using external drives with FAT32 or ExFat.

Any idea how I could improve this without losing the annexed data?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the easy option would be to split in two repositories:

1. git bare repo holding the files
2. local clone of 1. as workdir